# UIAScrollView's scrollToElementWithName() not working

Tags: scroll, ios-ui-automation

I am trying my first hand on UIAutomation. I had a scrollview inside which I had more sub-scrollviews. I am able to tap first 6 visible sub-scrollview but later when I try to tap on 7th it says "tap point is not within bounds of screen". So I tried with following solution but none of these works.
1. scrollToElementWithName("name") does not scrolls
2. scrollUP or scrollDown directly scroll to top/bottom. It doesn't stop in the middle
3. I also tried to scrollToVisible() method of UIAElement class on sub-scrollView object but it says, "scrollToVisible cannot be used because a scrollable ancestor element is not visible."

I have not tried with scrollToElementWithValueForKey as I am confused with what key-value pair should I use. 
Please suggets. Any help is appreciable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found other way to perform scrolling. I used dragFromToForDuration() method to drag the screen so as to make the tap point of next sub-scrollview visible. And this works fine now. But I am running into another issu now which is opened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171065/simulator-timed-out-issue-while-running-uiautomation-in-ios).

Answer (score 1):

If you get an Error message like :  "`scrollToVisible` cannot be used because a scrollable ancestor element is not visible.", when using the `scrollToVisible()`  method of UIAElement class , the pdf or the content is not loaded yet and you are tying to scroll that content which is not yet loaded.

The solutions to fix this issue are :

**1**. Add some delay until the content is loaded

**2**. Use the retry method after every x sec for y times. (Refer: retry method from `tuneup js` by Alex vollmeter)

**3**. If the activity indicator (loading spinner exists) then wait until that element is visible.
Using any of the three solutions will resolve this error.
Also, the similar thing applies for `scrollToElementWithName()`. If the element is not loaded yet and you are tying to access it.

Hope that helps :)

--Swathy.