# Simulator timed out issue while running UIAutomation in iOS

Tags: ios, timeout, ios-simulator, ios-ui-automation

I am running UIAutomation scripts. Some times script executes successfully while other times it crashes saying

> Simulator session timed out

and this message is also at different interval.

If I have for loop while executing script, then somes it executes thrice, sometimes till 10 iteration some time even till 25th iteration & in between it creases with above alert.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  File a report at http://bugreport.apple.com